# svg transform text aliased in chrome, how can I fix it?

Tags: svg

```
<g transform="translate(75, 176) rotate(-90)">
    <text>This is my Y Axis</text>
</g>
```

Looks terrible in chrome

[image: chrome]

and better in Edge

[image]

but nowhere near as good as non-rotated text

[image]

Why? How can I improve the look of the rotated text?

**UPDATE** I didn't include my code since this is React so presumably what is rendered is more important, which I took from the Chrome inspector. My code is below:

```
const CustomAxisLabel = (props/*: {

 title: string,
 xAxis: boolean,
 // note these next two are passed down from the parent XYPlot/Flexible*XYPlot
 innerWidth: number,
 innerHeight: number
 }*/) => {
  // since we rotate the y label, we have to adjust it to center
  // (ideally we'd rotate about the correct origin, but i couldn't get that working)
  const yLabelOffset = {
    y: props.innerHeight / 2 + props.title.length * 3, // '3' might be different for you depending on your font size/char width
    x: 47
  };

  const xLabelOffset = {
    x: props.innerWidth / 2 - props.title.length * 1.5,
    y: 1.23 * props.innerHeight // 1.2 was enough for me to get it below x axis. you may need a diff't #
  };
  const transform = props.xAxis
    ? `translate(${xLabelOffset.x}, ${xLabelOffset.y})`
    : `translate(${yLabelOffset.x}, ${yLabelOffset.y}) rotate(-90)`;

  return (
    <g
      transform={transform}
    >
      <text>{props.title}</text>
    </g>
  );
};
```

If it matters, rendered css for the  tag:

[image]

and for the  tag:

[image]

**UPDATE2:**

[Fiddle with full HTML copied from chrome inspector](https://jsfiddle.net/davegravy/2s0koycp/)

Comment: Could you please provide the full code in your question? You can put it in a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I added code.

Comment: Can you copy paste the rendered HTML? The fact that it's generated by React should change the display of the HTML.

Comment: I added a fiddle with the full HTML copied from chrome

Comment: Oops, I was thinking *React should **not** change the display* but I wrote the opposite, sorry. Thanks for adding a fiddle.

Comment: While I can't see differences on my machine, you could try to set in CSS [`text-rendering`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#TextRenderingProperty) to `geometricPrecision` or `optimizeLegibility`.